# Python sklearn-pandas Transform Multiple Columns at the same time error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am using python with `pandas` and `sklearn` and trying to use the new and very convenient `sklearn-pandas`.

I have a big data frame and need to transform multiple columns in a similar way.

I have multiple column names in the variable `other`
the source code documentation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas)
states explicitly there is a possibility of transforming multiple columns with the same transformation, but the following code does not behave as expected:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, LabelEncoder

mapper = DataFrameMapper([[other[0],other[1]],LabelEncoder()])
mapper.fit_transform(df.copy())
```

I get the following error:

> raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
>   ValueError: ['EFW', 'BPD']: bad input shape (154, 2)

When I use the following code, it works great:

```
cols = [(other[i], LabelEncoder()) for i,col in enumerate(other)]
mapper = DataFrameMapper(cols)
mapper.fit_transform(df.copy())
```

To my understanding, both should work well and yield same results.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encounter here, is that the two snippets of code are completely different in terms of data structure.

`cols = [(other[i], LabelEncoder()) for i,col in enumerate(other)]` builds a list of tuples. Do note that you can shorten this line of code to:

```
cols = [(col, LabelEncoder()) for col in other]
```

Anyway, the first snippet, `[[other[0],other[1]],LabelEncoder()]` results in a list containing two elements: a list and a `LabelEncoder` instance. Now, it is documented that you can transform multiple columns through specifying:

> > Transformations may require multiple input columns. In these cases, the column names can be specified in a list:
> >
> > > mapper2 = DataFrameMapper([
> > >       (['children', 'salary'], sklearn.decomposition.PCA(1))
> > >        ])

This is a `list` containing `tuple(list, object)` structured elements, not  `list[list, object]` structured elements.

If we take a look at the source code itself,

```
class DataFrameMapper(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Map Pandas data frame column subsets to their own
    sklearn transformation.
    """

    def __init__(self, features, default=False, sparse=False, df_out=False,
                 input_df=False):
        """
        Params:
        features    a list of tuples with features definitions.
                    The first element is the pandas column selector. This can
                    be a string (for one column) or a list of strings.
                    The second element is an object that supports
                    sklearn's transform interface, or a list of such objects.
                    The third element is optional and, if present, must be
                    a dictionary with the options to apply to the
                    transformation. Example: {'alias': 'day_of_week'}
```

It is also clearly stated in the class definition that the features argument to `DataFrameMapper` is required to be a list of tuples, where the elements of the tuple may be lists.

As a last note, as to why you actually get your error message: The `LabelEncoder` transformer in `sklearn` is meant for labeling purposes on 1D arrays. As such, it is fundamentally unable to handle 2 columns at once and will raise an Exception. So, if you want to use the `LabelEncoder`, you will have to build N tuples with 1 columnname and the transformer where N is the amount of columns you wish to transform.

Comment: And the error disappears if you use the `MinMaxScaler()` instead of `LabelEncoder()`? -- it seems `LabelEncoder` is not able to deal with multiple columns at once, better yet..explicitly checks for 1D data.

Comment: @captainshai Yes. LabelEncoder is meant for labels and only handles single dimension arrays. For each column you want to transform, you need to use a separate LabelEncoder().